# Command's output does not show up in the gradle test report's Standard output

Tags: java, groovy, junit, gradle

I execute some commands in my JUnit test code written in groovy but the command's output does not show up in the gradle test report. Does anyone know why this happen?

Following is my simplified code:

```
package org.myorg.myapp

import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor
import org.junit.Test

class MyTest {

  @Test
  void executelsCommand() {
    println("Started.")

    String line = "ls"
    CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line)
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor()
    int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine)

    println("Finished.")
  }

}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.3'
  testCompile 'org.apache.commons:commons-exec:1.2'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

test {
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

The result of executing the above code is following:

[image: The result of executing the above code]

If I execute the above code in my eclipse using Run As -> JUnit Test, ls command's output successfully shows up in the Console window.

[image: ls command's output shows up in the Console window]

Answer (score 2):

In your build script, add:

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work. I have edited my question with the build.gradle.